# How to make all types of HTML links clickable in Android TextView? (Working Solution! With mailto: and tel:)

Tags: android, html, kotlin, textview, href

### Intro

I was spending the last three days with this problem. Digging through multiple SO posts, all with different approaches for different Android Versions and different use-cases. I hope to finally end this discussion and questions with this self-answered post.

### The problem

You have HTML code with links in it. You want to make use of the `TextView.fromHtml()` method to display this HTML in a TextView. You want to keep any kind of link clickable. You will face the problem that there are several possible types of links. All of them are handled differently by the TextView:

1. `<a href='http://www.google.com'>A custom text</a>`
2. `<a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>`
3. `<a href='mailto:test@test.com'>An email link</a>`
4. `<a href='mailto:test@test.com'>test@test.com</a>`
5. `<a href='tel:+1234567890'>A phone number link</a>`
6. `<a href='tel:+1234567890'>+1234567890</a>`
7. `plain text http(s)://www.google.com`

For each of them there exists an easy solution. But it is very hard to make them **ALL** work together.

### What does not work

If you need to handle all of the listed types of links, then forget about any combination of the following techniques. They are only useful in case you need to make a subset of these types clickable:

- `android:autoLink="[all|web|whatever]"`
- `Linkify.addLinks(...)`
- `TextView.setMovementMethod()`

Comment: Should mention that this applies to kotlin

Comment: I will add the tag, thanks for the input. However, Java or Kotlin has nothing to do with the problem. The code should be very easy to be converted into Java if someone is still using it or has some legacy project to fix.

Answer (score 0):

### The copy/paste solution

Replace your `TextView` with this `LinkedTextView` and call its `setHtml(html: String?)` method. The code is heavily documented, so it should be easy to understand what is going on and how to extend or change it to similar needs:

````
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.text.Html
import android.text.Spannable
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan
import android.text.style.URLSpan
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.core.text.getSpans
import androidx.core.text.toSpannable
import de.bvb09.android.R

/**
 * This class is worth gold. If you are an Android dev, copy/paste it now and cherish it.
 *
 * What does it do? It will make all forms of HTML links clickable in TextViews. There are
 * many different types of such links:
 *
 * 1. <a href='http://www.google.com'>A custom text</a>
 * 2. <a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>
 * 3. <a href='mailto:test@test.com'>An email link</a>
 * 4. <a href='mailto:test@test.com'>test@test.com</a>
 * 5. <a href='tel:+1234567890'>A phone number link</a>
 * 6. <a href='tel:+1234567890'>+1234567890</a>
 * 7. plain text http(s)://www.google.com
 *
 * Making all of these clickable might seem like a simple task, but it is a
 * journey of pain. Mainly because there 3 Android settings that are interfering with each other
 * and almost any combination of them will fuck up at least one of the different HTML
 * examples above:
 *
 * * `android:autoLink` as XML attribute of the TextView
 * * `TextView.setMovementMethod`
 * * `LinkifyCompat.addLinks()`
 *
 * Forget about these settings and only use this class. 
 * Do not use any of these mechanism outside of this class.
 * Your XML layout can be as simple as this:
 *
 * ```
 *  <your.view.package.LinkedTextView 
 *      android:id="@+id/tv_text_content"
 *      android:layout_width="match_parent"
 *      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 *      app:html="@{html}"
 *      />
 * ```
 *
 */
class LinkedTextView : AppCompatTextView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    init {
        movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

        // set any color of your liking or set it individually via xml `android:linkTextColor`
        val linkColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bvb_yellow)
        setLinkTextColor(linkColor)
    }

    fun setHtml(html: String?) {
        html ?: return

        // --------------------
        // This is just to prove that this TextView is working with all types of links.
        // Delete these lines after testing.
        val html = "" +
                "<a href=\"http://google.com\">http://google.com</a><br/>" +
                "<a href=\"http://bing.com\">A text link</a><br/>" +
                "<a href=\"mailto:test@test.com\">test@test.com</a><br/>" +
                "<a href=\"mailto:test@test.com\">An email link</a><br/>" +
                "<a href=\"tel:+1234567890\">A phone number link</a><br/>" +
                "<a href=\"tel:+1234567890\">+1234567890</a><br/>" +
                "http://www.yahoo.com<br/>" +
                "https://www.duckduckgo.com"
        // --------------------


        // `fromHtml` does the following:
        // * strip all HTML tags
        // * create URLSpans for these HTML tags
        // * return a [Spanned] with the tag-free text and according URLSpans set to that text
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        val fromHtml = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
        } else {
            Html.fromHtml(html)
        }.toSpannable()

        // extract all URLSpan
        val urlSpans = fromHtml.getSpans(0, fromHtml.length, URLSpan::class.java) ?: emptyArray()

        // replace all URLSpans with ClickableSpans
        urlSpansToClickableSpan(fromHtml, urlSpans)

        // set ClickableSpans to all plain text links
        plainTextLinksToClickableSpan(fromHtml)

        // set the result to the TextView
        text = fromHtml
    }

    /**
     * UrlSpans are not working properly for HTML links that have a non-http text
     * between the <a>-Tag (e.g. <a href="http://bing.com">A text link</a>).
     *
     * To make them work, we have to replace all UrlSpans with ClickableSpans and add
     * the click behaviour ourselves.
     */
    private fun urlSpansToClickableSpan(spannable: Spannable, urlSpans: Array<URLSpan>) {
        urlSpans.forEach { span ->
            val start = spannable.getSpanStart(span)
            val end = spannable.getSpanEnd(span)
            val flags = spannable.getSpanFlags(span)

            spannable.setSpan(getClickAction(span.url), start, end, flags)

            // removing the old URLSpan is essential to avoid overlapping Spans!!
            spannable.removeSpan(span)
        }
    }

    /**
     * In [urlSpansToClickableSpan] we handled all HTML links. This method will now
     * create ClickableSpans for the remaining plain text links.
     *
     * By default Android is opening the browser for such links automatically.
     * So this method is just here to give you the option to create a custom behaviour
     * for such links.
     */
    private fun plainTextLinksToClickableSpan(spannable: Spannable) {

        // iterate over all http words
        Regex("\\s(http[^\\s]+)")
            .findAll(spannable)
            .forEach { matchResult ->

                // get start and end index of the regex match
                val startIndex = matchResult.range.first
                val endIndex = matchResult.range.last

                // Check if we already have a span for these indices
                val isPlainTextMatch = spannable.getSpans<ClickableSpan>(startIndex, endIndex).isEmpty()

                // If not, it is a plain text link -> add the ClickableSpan
                if (isPlainTextMatch) {
                    spannable.setSpan(getClickAction(matchResult.value.trim()), startIndex, endIndex, 0)
                }
            }
    }


    /**
     * @return A [ClickableSpan] with our custom click action depending on the URL of the Span
     */
    private fun getClickAction(url: String) = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            ContextCompat.startActivity(view.context, intent, bundleOf())
        }
    }
}
````

Enjoy!

Comment: In Kotlin, I'd define it as an extension function so you don't need a subclass. It's easier to work directly with the basic TextView in XML, and then if AppCompat, Material Components, or any other theme library swaps out TextViews for their own subclass, it will still work.

Comment: sure, you could also do that. The logic stays the same :) Another approach would be to define a BindingAdapter which implements the `setHtml()` method. All valid ways to solve this problem.